# How to fetch only one record only once using sql in statement?

Tags: sql, join, row-number

I am having two tables consider a and b,the table a has columns c,d,e,f.Consider that the joining column for two tables is 'f'.I want to retrieve data where condition in ('c','d','e') but the condition e should occur only once with the combination of f and the date in ascending order.Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  And what does table `b` have to do with anything?

Comment: There are some other columns from table b to extract but the conditions are given for table a.

Comment: The more specific your question is, the easier it is for the community to help you.

Comment: Select c.name,o.address from Customers c inner join Orders o on c.cid=o.cid where c.name in ('a','b','c','d') but d should occur only once .Is the question ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing the use of `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by f, e order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: No,tried using the row number too let me write the query.